# FDO Layers from MAPGUIDE

Tags: openlayers-3, mapguide

I am trying to add MapGuide Layers that are NOT jpg as shown in the example.

```js
var mdf = 'Library://Samples/Sheboygan/Maps/Sheboygan.MapDefinition';
var agentUrl =
  'http://data.mapguide.com/mapguide/mapagent/mapagent.fcgi?USERNAME=Anonymous';
var bounds = [-87.865114442365922,
  43.665065564837931, -87.595394059497067,
  43.823852564430069
];
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Image({
      extent: bounds,
      source: new ol.source.ImageMapGuide({
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        url: agentUrl,
        useOverlay: false,
        metersPerUnit: 111319.4908, //value returned from mapguide
        params: {
          MAPDEFINITION: mdf,
          FORMAT: 'PNG'
        },
        ratio: 2
      })
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [-87.7302542509315, 43.744459064634],
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    zoom: 12
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.4.0/ol.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.4.0/ol.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

My layer source is from a SHP file this format shown in the sample code above  is for PNG, and or Image data type.
What is the correct coding to use a Map definition or data source that is data not an image?

Thanks, and thanks for understanding that I am new to this and may be asking far more questions...

Comment: What you are looking for is WFS (Web Feature Service). MapGuide supports that. For the OpenLayers side, you'll find a detailed answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29219829/how-to-add-shapefiles-to-a-bing-map-using-openlayers-3/29221751#29221751. For the MapGuide side, I don't know the format of MapGuide WFS URLs, but you should be able to figure that out by consulting the MapGuide documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however editing the code from that link to be  "var vectorSource = new ol.source.ServerVector({
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),  loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {    var url =https://mapguide.enviroag.com/mapguide/TexasMajorRodas/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&' +'request=GetFeature&typename=osm:Texas_Majors&outputFormat=json' + '&srsname=EPSG:3857&bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857';
    $.ajax(url).then(function(response) ...nothing appears on the map.

Comment: Check the network tab of your javascript console to see if your wfs response has proper geojson content.

Comment: I see nothing from or about WFS....I don't think I have proper resource URL, however not finding much help on what that should be..on the MapGuide side of this

Comment: https://mapguide.enviroag.com/mapguide/fusion/templates/mapguide/slate/test.html- This appears to connect with no error(s) however the map does not display anything?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your issue, but the current stable versions of MapGuide [do not support](http://trac.osgeo.org/fdo/ticket/863) coordinate system transformations via WFS.

The [mapguide-rest](https://github.com/jumpinjackie/mapguide-rest) project is the best way I know of to get transformed vector features from MapGuide. I used mapguide-rest to get transformed vectors in GeoJSON format.