# servervector does not build the map

Tags: openlayers-3

I am trying to use **ServerVector**
In `Geoserver` I have built `WFS` and get the preview normally.

But, in `ol3-ServerVector`,   although I get features in FireBug, but I am not able to build the map.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I gave here should give you the basic code required to get this done: [How to add shapefiles to a Bing Map using Openlayers 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29219829/how-to-add-shapefiles-to-a-bing-map-using-openlayers-3/29221751#29221751)

If you can see requests being sent, but don't see anything on the map, then you are probably doing something wrong with projections. In the answer I linked above, pay special attention to all places where projections are defined (look for EPSG:3857).